# Join table in laravel - Pagination not working

Tags: php, join, laravel, foreach, pagination

```
//get all the data of both table

foreach($tables as $table){

 $table_history = $table.'_history';
 $result[] = DB::table($table)->join($table_history, $table.user_id, '=',$table_history.user_id )->paginate(5);

}
```

When I tried

```
<?php echo $result->links(); ?>
```

It doesn't return anything.

And also trying to print_r the result

```
<?php print_r($result); ?>
```

It returned:

```
Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator Object ( [factory:protected] => Illuminate\Pagination\Factory Object ( [request:protected] => Illuminate\Http\Request Object ( [json:protected] => [sessionStore:protected] => [attributes] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag Object ( [parameters:protected] => Array ( ) ) [request] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag Object ( [parameters:protected] => Array ( ) ) [query] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag Object ( [parameters:protected] => Array ( ) ) [server] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ServerBag Object ( [parameters:protected] => Array ( [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => C:\xampp\htdocs\system101\public [REMOTE_ADDR] => ::1 [REMOTE_PORT] => 53241 [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => PHP 5.4.7 Development Server [SERVER_PROTOCOL]
```

I tried making the variable into an array:

`$result[] = DB::table('user')->join('position', user.user_id, '=',position.user_id )->get();`

It displays all the data needed.  But still,  I did change it to `->paginate(5)` It returned like the one above.

How can I display the paginated links? Or is there any other way how to do pagination?

Comment: What you get is not an error it's just an instance of the `Paginator`. What does `$result->getItems()` return?

Comment: It displays Array(). @ lukasgeiter

Comment: Which means that your query returns nothing. Are you maybe looking for `leftJoin()` instead of `join()`?

Comment: Why is that @lukasgeiter? I used join() because i need all the col of both tables. Help me with this please

Comment: Do you have any records with the same `user.user_id` and `position.user_id`? (Also I just saw that you probably forgot the quotes in the code in your question: `join('position', 'user.user_id' ...`)

Comment: I added some explanations above @lukasgeiter. Still the same output. Pagination is not working on.

Comment: How many rows do you get? More than 5?

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea what could cause this. Let me know if you find something out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Join takes only string parameters**

Laravel join syntax

`join(string $table, string $one, string $operator = null, string $two = null, string $type = 'inner', bool $where = false)`

**To fix make your db attributes strings in your query**

```
$result = DB::table('user')
             ->join('position', 'user.user_id', '=', 'position.user_id')->paginate(5);
```

**Moreover...**

```
foreach($tables as $table):

    $table_history = $table.'_history';

    $result = DB::table($table)
                    ->join("$table_history", "$table.user_id", '=', "$table_history.user_id")
                    ->paginate(5);

endforeach;
```

Comment: i've edited my question @rafael . Please help me get this one.

Comment: I've already answered you question. You need to add quotes appropriately.  I edited my answer and added "moreover" let me know how it goes